# Delete specific string in some rows in one column in R

Tags: r

I want to delete specific characters ".." in a row when they appear in a specific column. Otherwise, I want R to ignore the other rows and leave them as is. Example dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(region = c("Region A", "..Region B", "Region C", "..Region D"),
                 value = c("12", "9", "11", "18"))
```

```
Desired output:

region         value
Region A       12
Region B       9
Region C       11
Region D       18
```

I've tried, str_extract, sub, and gsub:

```
df$region <- str_extract(df$region, "..")
df$region <- sub("..", "", df$region)
df$region <- gsub("..","", as.character(df$region))
```

But each of them deletes more characters than just the ".." or deletes the string entirely. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `sub("..", "", df$region, fixed =TRUE)`

Comment: `df$region <- trimws(df$region, whitespace = '\\.')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot `.` is a special regex character selecting any character. To target real dots we have to escape the dot with a double backslash `\\.`:

```r
df <- data.frame(region = c("Region A", "..Region B", "Region C", "..Region D"),
                 value = c("12", "9", "11", "18"))

df$region <- gsub("\\.", "", df$region)

df
#>     region value
#> 1 Region A    12
#> 2 Region B     9
#> 3 Region C    11
#> 4 Region D    18
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: That worked thank you! But I don't understand why. What does "escape the dot" mean and what does "perl" do?

Comment: Why do you need perl? PCRE is sufficient for this.

Comment: @Jackie: I added some explanation regarding escpaing the dot and onyambu is correct, we don't need PERL here, R's dafaul regex engine TRE can do the job.

Comment: @onyambu: You are correct, we don't need PERL in this case. I usually use `PERL = TRUE` as my personal default.